# Selenium testcase execution speed issues

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I have a issue with selenium where i am able to pass the testcase, but the issue is the execution of the testcase is very quick. Is there any way or attribute through which i can control the speed of the execution. I have been facing this problem big time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Below is my script for reference.

```
package test.selenium;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test{
    WebDriver driver;

    public TrafficGroupUpdateTestNG() {
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Use Internet Explorer and set driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                "D:\\IBM\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        // And now use this to visit URL
        driver.get("URL Of JSP");
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public final void test() {
        final WebElement formElement = driver.findElement(By.id("search"));

        final Select drelement = new Select(drelement.findElement(By.id("my_input")));


        drelement.selectByIndex(0);

        final WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("Submit"));
        submit.click();

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to slow the execution down? If your test is passing... ?

Comment: Not positive, but I think you are actually wanting to put a common wait as part of the element action?  That way it won't act on an element until it is actually actionable?  That is better than just slowing the whole script down.

Comment: @mutt : I agree with you. Is there any solution for it?.How should it be approached. Possibly making it a bit slower would help.

Comment: @mark: Eventually when the action occurs it disappears within no time.. Also if i am trying multiple testcases(mentioned in testNG.xml)  one or the other two gets failed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

A convinient way for making the page wait.

Comment: This is fine but this is no proper Solution I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like elements from AJAX calls are not visible or ready when document.ready status is updated.  Working with my webdevs, I had them add a waiting class while they loaded things and remove it when they're done.

As a result, I was able to create [this "WaitForPageLoad" method](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/09/webdriver-wait-for-document-ready-and.html) that waits until AJAX is finished.  It's in C# but simple enough to translate into Java.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can control speed of the execution..

Implicity wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

by providing this imlicity wait, webdriver waits until 20 seconds before it returns object not found

explicit wait

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
>             wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));

This will wait explicitly for given element..